# Creating/initializing task without starting it immediately

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mvvm

I want to create/initialize a Task object from a async Task method without starting it directly. When searching online I only find answer with Task created from void methods.

This is the task method I want to execute. As I need to do some web requests async, the method needs to be async. I want to do exception handling as well, so it can't be an `async void`.

```
private async Task WebRequestTask()
{
    try
    {
        string ResponseText = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://fakeurl.com");
        // process response code
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         // handle error
    }
}
```

This is my main method where I want to create the task:

```
private void StartTask()
{
    TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Task RequestTask = ... // here I want to initialize the task without starting

    // chain continuation tasks to RequestTask

    RequestTask.Start();
}
```

I've tried following solutions but nothing answers my need:

**Solution 1**

```
Task RequestTask = new Task(WebRequestTask); 
Task RequestTask = WebRequestTask;
```

-> both cause a compiler error

**Solution  2**

```
Task RequestTask = Task.Run(WebRequestTask);
```

-> this start the task async and the current method continues (but here it could be possible an exception is thrown before the continuation tasks are chained)

**Solution 3**

```
Task RequestTask = WebRequestTask();
```

-> this start the task synchronously and chaining happens after the task is finished

**Solutions 4**

```
Task<Task> OuterTask = new Task<Task>(LoginToAzure);
await LoginAzureTask.Unwrap();
```

-> this start the outer task but the inner task is never called

How can I attach this Task method to an Task object, so that I can first attach continuation tasks/set some options and then start it? When it's possible, I'd like to use the cancellation token as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why you want to chain the continuations before starting the task? From the point of view of a `Task`, it makes no difference whether the continuation will be attached before starting, during the execution, or after the completion of a `Task`. The `Task` class is thread-safe, and will accept any continuation and invoke it at the right moment in any case.

Comment: When I debug my example, I can see the breakpoint on the fifth line of my `WebRequestTask` method is reached before the line in the `StartTask` method where I attach the second continuation task (first is `OnlyOnCanceled`, second is `OnlyOnFaulted`). Say there is an error/exception happening on the second line of the WebRequestTask, so no OnError continuation has been attach and wont be triggered. Or I am wrong on this?

Comment: AFAIK the continuations `OnlyOnFaulted`, `OnlyOnCanceled` etc will be invoked regardless of the timing, in respect with the task's completion. If this was not the case, asynchronous programming would be extremely awkward, and riddled with race conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asynchronous methods that are implemented with the `async` keyword are creating "hot" `Task`s, in other words `Task`s that are already started. You can defer the execution of an `async` method by wrapping it in another `Task`, thus creating a nested `Task<Task>`, like this:

```
private void StartTask()
{
    TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = TokenSource.Token;
    Task<Task> taskTask = new Task<Task>(() => WebRequestAsync(token));
    Task task = taskTask.Unwrap(); // The task is not started yet

    // Chain continuations to task

    taskTask.RunSynchronously(TaskScheduler.Default);
    // The task is now started
}

private async Task WebRequestAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    string responseText = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(
        "https://fakeurl.com", cancellationToken);
    // Process response text
}
```

The `taskTask` variable is the wrapper that represents just the execution of the `WebRequestAsync` method, not the completion of the `Task` that this method creates. The wrapper task is completed immediately after calling the [`RunSynchronously`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.runsynchronously) method, and after that point your code will have no use for it. The `task` variable "[unwraps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap)" the wrapper, and represents the actual asynchronous web request. It is completed when the asynchronous operation completes.

As you can see this technique is rather cumbersome. You'll rarely see it in application code, because pure async-await composition is more convenient to use.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I'll already tried the unwrap thing (see initial post) but withou the RunSynchronously method. Wouldn't that block the current treat (in my case UI)?

Comment: @Lenwe606 normally not, assuming that the `WebRequestAsync` is properly implemented, according to [Microsoft's guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#initiating-an-asynchronous-operation). If you have reasons to believe that the `WebRequestAsync` contains blocking code, then instead of `RunSynchronously` use the [`Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.start) method, in which case the `WebRequestAsync` will be invoked on the `ThreadPool`.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. When using `RunSynchronously` the main method is blocked until the first await in the WebRequestTask is executed. When using the `Start` method, the main method finishes, the WebRequest method is started and everything is working as expected. Thanks for this solution!

Answer (score 2):

> I want to create/initialize a Task object from a async Task method without starting it directly.

The best way to do this is to use delegates. E.g.:

```
private void StartTask()
{
  TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  Func<Task> taskFactory = () => WebRequestTask(TokenSource);

  // chain continuation tasks

  Task task = taskFactory(); // Start the task
  ... // await the task or save it somewhere   
}
```

Side note: I strongly recommend implementing "chain continuation tasks" using `await` rather than `ContinueWith`. `await` is a clean and safe approach; `ContinueWith` is a low-level, dangerous method.

Comment: "await the task or ..." : how to do that in a void method?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: A local `async` method is one solution.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the delegate thing. I want to setup multiple tasks and run them in parallell so await is not an option

Comment: I tried this delegate way, but then the ContinueWith method are not availabe because the object it is a function . setting the continuation after Task task = taskFactory() is possible but the task is again already started

Comment: @Lenwe606: You shouldn't compose tasks with `ContinueWith` anyway. You compose tasks with `await`, e.g., `taskFactory = async () => { await WebRequestTask(); await SomeOtherTask(); };`

Answer (score 1):

> I want to do exception handling as well, so it can't be an `async void`.

Since you are handling the error inside WebRequestTask() that doesn't really matter.

The preferred option would be to make StartTask an `async Task` but if that isn't possible, make it `async void`. That takes care of the "without starting" requirement too.

So, keep it simple:

```
private async void StartTask()
{
    TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    try
    {
      await WebRequestTask(TokenSource.Token);

      // here I want to initialize the task without starting -- irrelevant in an async void

      await otherTask();  // continuation(s)
    }
    catch()
    {
       // handle residual errors
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment. In my case, I want to setup multiple tasks and run them in parallell. With await, the tasks are async but the main methods waits between each execution. As for the exception handling, I do catch them in the task method itself (to write to a log) but to notify the user of an error (ex via messagebox) I need to know that in the main method. Also I want no notification on cancelled

Comment: "multiple tasks in parallell" is a far cry from "continuations". But easily done with `await myTasks.Whenall()`.