# Batching async operations to run sequentially in .NET Core C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

I am learning finer control over scheduling async operations in .NETCore C#.

Suppose I have a collection of async Tasks that I want to batch into a predefined batch size and execute these batches sequentially.
In each individual batch, the tasks should progress parallelly.

Here's how I am trying to achieve this ([.NET Fiddle workspace](https://dotnetfiddle.net/65JkE2))-

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new Program();
        obj.RunAsync().Wait();
    }
    
    public async Task RunAsync()
    {
        var BATCH_SIZE = 2;
        
        var taskArr = new List<Task> {
            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.5)).ContinueWith((ante) => { Console.WriteLine("First"); }),
            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4.5)).ContinueWith((ante) => { Console.WriteLine("Second"); }),
            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)).ContinueWith((ante) => { Console.WriteLine("Third"); }),
            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5)).ContinueWith((ante) => { Console.WriteLine("Fourth"); }),
            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)).ContinueWith((ante) => { Console.WriteLine("Fifth"); }),
        };
        
        
        for (var i = 0; i<taskArr.Count; i+=BATCH_SIZE) {
            var remainingItems = Math.Min(BATCH_SIZE, taskArr.Count - i);
            
            Console.WriteLine("Batch start Idx -> {0} ; Size -> {1}", i, remainingItems);
            var curBatch = taskArr.GetRange(i,remainingItems);
            
            await Task.WhenAll(curBatch);
        }
    }
}
```

The output -

```
Batch start Idx -> 0 ; Size -> 2
Third
Fifth
Fourth
Second
First
Batch start Idx -> 2 ; Size -> 2
Batch start Idx -> 4 ; Size -> 1
```

I am expecting these 5 tasks to get batched and executed in goups of 2, and those 2 can execute parallelly. Here's my expectation (considering their delay durations) -

```
Batch start Idx -> 0 ; Size -> 2
Second
First
Batch start Idx -> 2 ; Size -> 2
Third
Fourth
Batch start Idx -> 4 ; Size -> 1
Fifth
```

TIA

Comment: The TPL may already have what you are looking for, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl particularly the dataflows

Comment: `await` does not start the tasks. They all start when you create them with `Task.Delay`. They all are executing before you even get to your `for` loop. Probably see https://stackoverflow.com/q/68692724/11683.

Comment: If you want to batch them two at a time, sequentially, put your code in a loop that starts two of them (in each pass through the loop), then `await`s a `WhenAll` of those two, and then loops back to get another pair of tasks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your batching isn't doing anything regarding when the tasks begin. By the time you have a `Task` instance, the task is already in progress. Instead of dealing with `Task`s, you need to use delegate types. Specifically, code that *returns* a `Task`, i.e., `Func<Task>`. That way, your code can invoke the delegate when it is ready for the task to begin.

Secondly, batching is now built-in to .NET via `Chunk`.

So, combining the above, an [updated Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4iuU0O) can look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new Program();
        obj.RunAsync().Wait();
    }
    
    public async Task RunAsync()
    {
        var BATCH_SIZE = 2;
        
        var operations = new List<Func<Task>> {
            () => Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.5)).ContinueWith((ante) => { Console.WriteLine("First"); }),
            () => Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4.5)).ContinueWith((ante) => { Console.WriteLine("Second"); }),
            () => Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)).ContinueWith((ante) => { Console.WriteLine("Third"); }),
            () => Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5)).ContinueWith((ante) => { Console.WriteLine("Fourth"); }),
            () => Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)).ContinueWith((ante) => { Console.WriteLine("Fifth"); }),
        };
        
        foreach (var batch in operations.Chunk(BATCH_SIZE)) {
            Console.WriteLine("Batch start Size -> {0}", batch.Length);

            // Start all the tasks in this batch
            var tasks = batch.Select(x => x()).ToList();

            // Wait for them to complete
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code sample to start the tasks per batch instead of all at once.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new Program();
        obj.RunAsync().Wait();
    }

    internal record TaskRunInfo(double Seconds, string Name);

    public async Task RunAsync()
    {
        var BATCH_SIZE = 2;

        var tasksToRun = new List<TaskRunInfo>() {
            new TaskRunInfo(5.5, "First"),
            new TaskRunInfo(4.5, "Second"),
            new TaskRunInfo(0.5, "Third"),
            new TaskRunInfo(2.5, "Fourth"),
            new TaskRunInfo(1.5, "Fifth")
        };


        for (var i = 0; i < tasksToRun.Count; i += BATCH_SIZE)
        {
            var remainingItems = Math.Min(BATCH_SIZE, tasksToRun.Count - i);

            Console.WriteLine("Batch start Idx -> {0} ; Size -> {1}", i, remainingItems);

            // start tasks here for 1 batch
            var curBatch = tasksToRun
                .GetRange(i, remainingItems)
                .Select(tri => Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tri.Seconds)).ContinueWith((ante) => { Console.WriteLine(tri.Name); }));

            // wait for batch
            await Task.WhenAll(curBatch);
        }
    }
}
```

The output will match what you expect:

```
Batch start Idx -> 0 ; Size -> 2
Second
First
Batch start Idx -> 2 ; Size -> 2
Third
Fourth
Batch start Idx -> 4 ; Size -> 1
Fifth
```